# Show url of index page with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have googled around and can't find an answer to my question so her I am. How can I force, with .htaccess, the filename of the index page to show when accessed by just the domain.

So if `http://example.com` is typed in `http://examples.com/home` will show in the address bar.

I have already used .htaccess to set home.php as the index page and remove the `.php` extension.

current .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex home.php

RewriteEngine on 

#add php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(phpscripts|js)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(?:/(.*?|))?/?$ /$1.php?$2 [L]

# redirect to .php-less link if requested directly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php\sHTTP/.+
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(phpscripts|js)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php /$1 [R=301,L]

#redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$1 [L,R=301]

#remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: please post your current `.htaccess`

Comment: You should put your www to non-www at the top, on your internal redirect what are you expecting ? /home and query string ? multiple directories ? Also `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php` does not work backwards as `$1` is set after.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want

```
RewriteRule ^$  /home [L,R=301]
```

This should catch both http://example.com and http://example.com/, and send them to http://example.com/home